# How to fix ts(2322) when using a case switch and generics?

Tags: typescript

I've been trying to use a switch case to map through values, using Typescript. For example, to get the string version of a number.

```
function getNumber(id) {
  switch (id) {
    case 1:
      return 'one';
    case 2:
      return 'two';
    case 3:
      return 'three';
  }
}
```

I want to use Typescript to make sure that a valid key is passed, therefore I've tried the following interface and used it to extract the allowed keys

```js
interface Numbers {
  1: 'one';
  2: 'two';
  3: 'three';
}

function getNumber<K extends keyof Numbers>(id: K) {
}
```

So far so good! In fact if I try `getNumber(4)` I get an error.

The issue happens with the return type. I'm expecting `Numbers[K] | void` to be returned.

```js
function getNumber<K extends keyof Numbers>(id: K): Numbers[K] | void {
  switch (id) {
    case 1:
      return 'one';
    case 2:
      return 'two';
    case 3:
      return 'three';
  }
}
```

But instead, I'm getting the error `Type '"one"' is not assignable to type 'void | Numbers[K]'.ts(2322)`.

I'm seeing this with TS 3.5.1 and with previous versions I don't see the issue.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you want to return `Numbers[K] | void` or `Number | void`?

Comment: Another casualty of [this change](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769), which [has broken some things](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types) in the name of soundness.  Realistically you'll have to use something like assertions.

Comment: I'd switch to [this form](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIFcC2AjaBnZAbwChlkBGALmQCIB7ECGgblOQCZqawB3OltgGYuYABZQITVgF9ixGOhAIwwBsgDmEMBhzQAPAGlkEAB6QQAEwIBrCAE86MNFlxQ8APgAUwC9QMBKah1XPABtAwBdIjYEBjwwZBAXfCDkt2QAXiIKLgYmABoOET4aQuFaMQkmZGlWMgkwdCgQRLSwnwiZYiA) if you can... not sure if it fits your use case, though

Comment: Your code works [in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Numbers%20%7B%0A%20%201%3A%20'one'%3B%0A%20%202%3A%20'two'%3B%0A%20%203%3A%20'three'%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20getNumber%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20Numbers%3E(id%3A%20K)%3A%20Numbers%5BK%5D%20%7C%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20switch%20(id)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20case%201%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20'one'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20case%202%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20'two'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20case%203%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20'three'%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D) and I tested it in a local project without error…

Comment: @Paleo you tried in TS3.5?

Comment: Here is a [very similar issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31672) in Github... marked "working as intended", so an assertion is going to be the answer here I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is happening because of a [pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) which made it into the 3.5 release.  It's known to be a [breaking change](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types).  In short, if you have a variable `x` of a type like `{a: string, b: number}`, a value `k` of the type `"a" | "b"`, and a value `v` of the type `string | number`, TypeScript used to let you write `x[k] = v`, and now it doesn't. Before, if `k` happened to be `"a"` and `v` happened to be `1`, the compiler would merrily give you a thumbs up and then you'd blow up at runtime when you evaluate `x.a.charAt(0)`.  By the same rule that governs the [`--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strictFunctionTypes) and the [improvement to calling unions of function types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types), the only *safe* thing to allow is the *intersection* of the types in question.  So you can only write `x[k] = w` if `w` is of type `string & number` and not `string | number`.  For such primitives, there are no values of both `string` and `number` type, so that means in practice it won't let you assign anything to `x[k]` without complaining.

Your code is very similar to a code in a [recently filed Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31672), which was closed as "working as intended".  This is unfortunate for a case like yours, but the solution here is the same solution that you use whenever you know something is safe but the compiler doesn't: the [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
  function getNumber<K extends keyof Numbers>(id: K): Numbers[K] {
    switch (id) {
      case 1:
        return "one" as Numbers[K]; // assertion
      case 2:
        return "two" as Numbers[K]; // assertion
      case 3:
        return "three" as Numbers[K]; // assertion
    }
    throw new Error("this can't happen"); // ensure the compiler that all paths return
  }
```

Another intentionally unsound tool you can use for functions is [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).  The compiler lets you give a "looser" implementation signature for type checking inside the function, and a "stricter" call signature (or set of signatures) for type checking function call sites.  This discrepancy gives you the room you need to overcome this particular error.  Note that it's morally equivalent to a type assertion but doesn't require as much typing in each return statement:

```
  // call signature: strict
  function getNumber<K extends keyof Numbers>(id: K): Numbers[K];
  // impl signature: loose
  function getNumber(id: keyof Numbers): Numbers[keyof Numbers] {
    switch (id) {
      case 1:
        return "one";
      case 2:
        return "two";
      case 3:
        return "three";
    }
  }
```

Finally, and I don't know if this meets your use case, you can give up `switch` entirely and use a properly typed object and use index access.  This is still acceptable in TS3.5:

```
    function getNumber<K extends keyof Numbers>(id: K): Numbers[K] {
      const numbers: Numbers = { 1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three" };
      return numbers[id];
    }
```

Okay, hope that helps you.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=interface%20Numbers%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%201%3A%20'one'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%202%3A%20'two'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%203%3A%20'three'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace%20ASSERTION%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20getNumber%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20Numbers%3E(id%3A%20K)%3A%20Numbers%5BK%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20switch%20(id)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%201%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22one%22%20as%20Numbers%5BK%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20assertion%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%202%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22two%22%20as%20Numbers%5BK%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20assertion%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%203%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22three%22%20as%20Numbers%5BK%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20assertion%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error(%22this%20can't%20happen%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20ensure%20the%20compiler%20that%20all%20paths%20return%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Anamespace%20OVERLOAD%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20call%20signature%3A%20strict%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20getNumber%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20Numbers%3E(id%3A%20K)%3A%20Numbers%5BK%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20impl%20signature%3A%20loose%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20getNumber(id%3A%20keyof%20Numbers)%3A%20Numbers%5Bkeyof%20Numbers%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20switch%20(id)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%201%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22one%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%202%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22two%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%203%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22three%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace%20MAPPING%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20getNumber%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20Numbers%3E(id%3A%20K)%3A%20Numbers%5BK%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20numbers%3A%20Numbers%20%3D%20%7B%201%3A%20%22one%22%2C%202%3A%20%22two%22%2C%203%3A%20%22three%22%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20numbers%5Bid%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)